# How to bench Scala with JMH in Intellij?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, benchmarking, jmh

I can't figure out how to do benchmarks of Scala programs in Intellij with JMH.

Here's what I've done so far:

**Added the JMH SBT-Plugin**

```
// build.sbt
name := "Project"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
enablePlugins(JmhPlugin)

// project/plugins.sbt
logLevel := Level.Warn
addSbtPlugin("pl.project13.scala" % "sbt-jmh" % "0.2.10")
```

Here is the [plugin's website](https://github.com/ktoso/sbt-jmh)

**Created a benchmark class**

```
// src/main/scala/MyBenchmark.scala
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark

class MyBenchmark {

    @Benchmark
    def test(): Unit = println("test")

}
```

**Created an SBT-Task in Intellij**

[image: Intellij Run Configuration]

But after running the task I just get an exception:

```
Annotation generator had thrown the exception.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openjdk.jmh.generators.reflection.RFClassInfo.getPackageName(RFClassInfo.java:51)
    at org.openjdk.jmh.generators.core.BenchmarkGenerator.validateBenchmark(BenchmarkGenerator.java:243)
    at org.openjdk.jmh.generators.core.BenchmarkGenerator.generate(BenchmarkGenerator.java:90)
    ....
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try to **add package name** in the benchmark class.

Because JMH is complaining about package name is not found.
org.openjdk.jmh.generators.reflection.RFClassInfo.**getPackageName**(RFClassInfo.java:51)

you should add the line like:

```
package your.path;
```